# Run ParseLiveQueryServer as standalone

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm running parse-server 2.3.8 using PM2 and I'm trying to run the LiveQueryServer with the same parse instance using PM2. Below is a snippet of the env in my ecosystem.json, which didn't work.

```
"env": {
    ...,
    "PARSE_SERVER_LIVE_QUERY_OPTIONS": {
        "classNames": ["MyClass", "MyOtherClass"],
        "appId": "myAppId",
        "masterKey": "myMasterKey",
        "serverURL": "https:://mydomain.com/parse"
    },
}
```

Next, I created an index.js and tried running the LiveQueryServer as standalone, which also didn't work. Here's the content of the index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;

var app = express();

var mount = 'parse';
var port = 1337;

var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port);
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer, {
    'appId': 'myAppID',
    'serverURL': 'http:localhost:' + port + '/' + mount,
    'logLevel': 'VERBOSE'
});
```

This is what I added to configure nginx to allow websockets, based on the [nginx tutorial](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) linked from Parse's documentation.

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream websocket {
    server localhost:1337;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    location /parse {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: In LiveQuery the server URL of the live query server must be the same like your parse server process. In your example I see that they are different, can you please recheck?

Comment: Turns out, on the client side, I was using the LiveQueryClient to connect, which possibly doesn't work with 2.3.8. Using query.subscribe it works fine. Regarding running with PM2, I "injected" an env variable to start the live query with parse in the cli definitions, and defined it in my ecosystem.json, which got to work fine. Also, I noticed, that starting 2.6.4, that this is included by default. So, I guess upgrading will make things easier :)